Who is Rory in this Doctor Who clip?
This answer features the following video clip from the Tenth Doctor era:



An interesting tidbit, from the part where David Tennant is speaking out of character, is the following sentence:

Now I have to talk for around about a minute without hesitation, deviation, or whatever the other thing is. It's like that panel game on Channel Four, like Rory just pointed out.

The panel game he's referring to is Just a Minute (on Radio Four, by the way, not Channel Four). But who is Rory? Obviously not Rory Williams, who wouldn't show up in the TARDIS for another few years after this was filmed. Since he's speaking out of character (as David Tennant rather than the Tenth Doctor), we can assume that this Rory isn't a Doctor Who character but rather a real person, some member of the cast or crew. Do we have any idea who it is?

There have been three series of Just a Minute on TV, one on ITV and two on the BBC. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_a_Minute (none on Channel Four though)

This is almost certainly the episode's Director of Photography, Rory Taylor.
Here he is, credited on the episode.


You can see the credits in full here on iplayer - https://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/episode/b007m0r9/doctor-who-20052022-series-3-8-human-nature. He's the only Rory on them.

That being said, the Doctor is a time traveller. He might have been referring to Rory Williams despite having not met him yet.

The Doctor might, but as far as I know, David Tennant isn't a time traveller (and he seems to be out of character in that clip).

@Randal'Thor - The Doctor is known to employ disguises. Perhaps David Tennant is merely one of these.

"I love disguises. Do you still like disguises?" That wasn't the Doctor ...

@Randal'Thor - According to SFX Magazine #189 , Russell T. Davis said "David Tennant is Doctor Who". So that's canon now.

@Valorum So now we know the real name of The Doctor!
